# Is it possible to compile the same control for both WPF and Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a complex control for Silverlight, and I need to have the same functionality in WPF. Any way to share the codebase?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x435tkbk.aspx + you can create project files for every platform.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek, thanks C.O.

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to create a project and add the files from other project as links. But some Silverlight controls have different properties, so conditional compilation should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really three aspects that would need to be shared:

1. Code files (such as *.cs *.vb)
2. XAML files (including themes)
3. Project files (such as *.csproj and *.vbproj)

As Jaroslav pointed out, you can use conditional complication for code files, which is supported by [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) and [VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x435tkbk.aspx). Keep in mind that Silverlight projects will by default define the SILVERLIGHT symbol, so you can use that in your conditional statements.

Another trick for code files is to use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). This allows you to put entire blocks of code that may only apply to Silverlight or WPF (but not both) in a single file. Then selectively include that file in your project.

Xaml files are a little tougher, as there are several things supported by WPF that are not supported by Silverlight (such as custom MarkupExtensions, etc). In practice, I simply duplicate the XAML files and merge as needed.

Project files must be maintained manually, which isn't that big of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [blog article](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2011/11/sharing-xaml-in-wpf-and-silverlight.html) about sharing `.xaml` files. The idea is to create a proxy control in your source code and use that control in `.xaml`:

```
namespace UnifiedXaml
{
    public class MyWrapPanel: WrapPanel { }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="UnifiedXaml.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ux="clr-namespace:UnifiedXaml">
    <ux:MyWrapPanel></ux:MyWrapPanel>
</UserControl>
```

If a control has different functionality in WPF and Silverlight, [use styles](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2011/11/sharing-xaml-in-wpf-and-silverlight.html).